# Where to change default translation language for drupal 7 while using entity translation module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm doing some translations, but I'm not sure how to change the "original content" to english. I can't seem to find a setting to change it to english. Anyone knows where to go for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to first delete your translations then you will be able the select another language under the dropdown box for the original content.